# Simple SQL statement

Tags: sql

I've been over-thinking this too much. Let's say I have a table TEST(refnum VARCHAR(5))

```
    |refnum|
    --------
    | 12345|
    | 56873|
    | 63423|
    | 12345|
    | 56873|
    | 12345|
```

I want my "view" to look something along the lines of this

```
    |refnum| count|
    ---------------
    | 12345|   3  |
    | 56873|   2  |
```

So the requirements are that the count for each refnum has to be > 1.
I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around this one. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, this looks like a simple

```
select refnum, count(*) from test group by refnum having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Wowzers. I was way overthinking this. Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

```
select refnum, count(*)
from table
group by refnum
```

Comment: This is close, but you're missing the Count of refnum > 1 requirement from the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL Server version:

```
CREATE VIEW vRefnumCounts AS
SELECT refnum, 
count(1) as [count] 
FROM test 
GROUP BY refnum 
HAVING count(1) > 1

SELECT *
FROM vRefnumCounts 
ORDER BY refnum
```

You said "view", but now I'm thinking you meant in the result set sense...